# is data structures necessary for a blockchain developer?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I want to know if i had to study data structures and algorithms for being a blockchain developer or a smart contract developer

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is yes, especially in the case of an ethereum dapps developer. As you know everything that changes the state of the blockchain needs to be paid. For this reason you should know the differences between using mappings, arrays etc. having this knowledge will make you develop smart contracts which execution cost less.